# Get n'th element with given class name with WebDriver

Tags: python, webdriver

I'm using `.find_element_by_class_name()` to get an element with a given class name. It seems that the returned element is the *first* with the class name. How can I get the *n*'th element with that class name?

Also, is it possible to get *all* the DOM elements with a given class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `find_elements_by_class_name,` notice the *elements* (plural) method which returns an iterator. To find the n'th element simply replace `num`: `find_elements_by_class_name('className')[num]`

This *should* return all DOM elements with the same class name.